# I want to match requests from a stream as fast as possible

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, stream, javascript-objects

I am using a Map to match incoming requests. I want to match those requests with their pair as soon as I get them. Order matters because it's first to come, first to match. Avoiding unnecessary operations is a requirement. My understanding is hash maps are faster than arrays iterations, and Maps maintain order. What is the best implementation for matching streaming objects with little to no space or time complexity? The data structure is not set in stone, it can be modified and encoded in whatever format optimizes, as long as the information is not lost. From my understanding, the best that can be achieved is O(n). Another problem I am facing with hashing is overwriting duplicates in the queue.  This is what I have.

```js
function* match(items, identity, remaining = new Map()) { 
  for (let item of items) {
   let id = identity(item);
   let pair = x =>({type:x.type==="passenger"? "driver": "passenger", direction:x.direction,          time:x.time})
    let  key = item=> item.type + item.direction + item.time;
    let candidate = remaining.get(key(pair(id)));
    if (candidate) {
      remaining.delete(key(pair(id)));
      yield [item, candidate];
    } else {
      remaining.set(key(id), item);
    }
  }
}
// Example:
let items = [{
    type: 'driver',
    direction: 'east',
    time: '9:15',
    name:['Archibald Trump']
  },{ 
    type: 'passenger',
    direction: 'east',
    time: '9:15',
    name:['Bacon Eater']
  },{ 
    type: 'passenger',
    direction: 'east',
    time: '9:15',
    name:['Banjo Barney']
  },{ 
    type: 'passenger',
    direction: 'east',
    time: '9:15',
    name:['Flimsy Stick']
  }, {
    type: 'passenger',
    direction: 'west',
    time: '9:30',
    name:['Big Red']
  },{
    type: 'passenger',
    direction: 'west',
    time: '9:35',
    name:['Hathaway Anne']
  }];
let remaining = new Map();
let pairs = match(items, item => item, remaining);
console.log('pairs',...pairs);
console.log('remaining',...remaining.values());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Encapsulation & Space Complexity:**

Your usage of `Set` is appropriate, but the code can be improved by encapsulating the matching functionality and getting rid of globals. I suggest a generator which yields matching pairs as follows with reduced space complexity:

```js
// Match items with first equal match:
function* match(items, equals, remaining = new Set()) {
  items: 
  for (let item of items) {
    for (let candidate of remaining) {
      if (equals(item, candidate)) {
        remaining.delete(candidate);
        yield [item, candidate];
        continue items;
      }
    }
    remaining.add(item);
  }
}

// Example:
let items = [1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4];
let remaining = new Set();
let pairs = match(items, (a, b) => a == b, remaining);

console.log(...pairs);
console.log(...remaining);
```

Depending on your items, you would need to supply a matching `equals` callback. In your case:

```
let pairs = match(
  items,
  (a, b) =>
    a.type !== b.type && 
    a.direction === b.direction &&
    a.time === b.time,
  remaining
);
```

**Optimization:**

If you could map requests to primitive identity values, you could replace the `for (let i of memo) { ... }` loop with a simple map lookup. The time complexity to pair n items then reduces to `O(n)`.

However, since you are not matching 'identical' items but items with opposing `type` property, this optimization is not directly applicable. You need to add another callback which gives us the expected id of a matching item.

Also, since you might encounter multiple request with identical identity, you need a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap):

```js
// Multimap insertion:
function insert(map, key, value) {
  let values = map.get(key);
  if (values) values.push(value);
  else map.set(key, [value]);
}

// Multimap retrieval:
function retrieve(map, key) {
  let values = map.get(key);
  if (values) {
    let value = values.pop();
    if (values.length === 0) map.delete(key);
    return value;
  }
}

// Match items with first identical match:
function* match(items, identity, match, remaining) {
  for (let item of items) {
    let candidate = retrieve(remaining, match(item));
    if (candidate) yield [item, candidate];
    else insert(remaining, identity(item), item);
  }
}

// Example:
let items = [{
  type: 'driver',
  direction: 'east',
  time: '9:15',
  name: ['Archibald Trump']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'east',
  time: '9:15',
  name: ['Bacon Eater']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'east',
  time: '9:15',
  name: ['Banjo Barney']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'east',
  time: '9:15',
  name: ['Flimsy Stick']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'west',
  time: '9:30',
  name: ['Big Red']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'west',
  time: '9:35',
  name: ['Hathaway Anne']
}];

let remaining = new Map();
let pairs = match(
  items,
  item => '' + (item.type == 'driver') + item.direction + item.time,
  item => '' + (item.type == 'passenger') + item.direction + item.time,
  remaining
);

console.log(...pairs);
console.log(...remaining.values());
```

The runtime complexity of above implementation is not easily determined as it depends on the runtime complexity of `Array.shift()` and `Array.push()`. However, if we assume that such key collisions are rare or assume that the JavaScript engine executed both of these methods in amortized constant time, we could still expect an O(n) runtime complexity for n items.

Answer (score 0):

Maps are faster than arrays. You can access an map key much quicker than looping over an array every time. Here is your example using an map.

```js
var pairs = [];
var memo = {};

function pair(item) {
    var key = item.type.toString() + item.direction + item.time;
    if(memo[key]) {
        pairs.push(item);
        delete memo[key];
    } else {
        memo[key] = item;
    }
}

var ar = [{
    type: true,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: true,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: true,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: true,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: true,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: true,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}, {
    type: false,
    direction: false,
    time: '9:00'
}];

for (let it of ar) {
  pair(it);
}

console.log('matching pairs: ', pairs);
console.log('left over nonmatching pairs:', Object.values(memo));
```